# Taking screenshot using Swift 5 returns a black image and not the app's screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of my app and then share it.

The problem I'm having is that when I take a screenshot and save it to the Photos app, the image that gets saved is completely black (and not the screenshot of my app).

How can I get the screenshot to be of my app? What am I missing?

```
func takeScreenshot() {
        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 0.0)
        self.view.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [img!], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

App is a single screen.
Swift 5
xCode 10

I've tried browsing other similar StackOverflow issues and tweaking my code to theirs but getting the same results. Hitting a wall and trying here.

Thanks for any help!

[image: View Controller Scene]

Comment: Does it make any difference to say `afterScreenUpdates: true`? Does it make any difference if you say `bounds.size, false, 0.0`?

Comment: Also what the heck is that extra view in the storyboard top level?

Comment: Ah, your suggestion "afterScreenUpdates: true" did it! Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a good explanation on the "extra view". I'm a rookie with xCode.

Comment: Cool, I’ll give that as an answer as it could be useful to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
 afterScreenUpdates: false
```

To

```
 afterScreenUpdates: true
```

That way there will be some drawing to snapshot.